# How can I re-run my script with user input

Tags: python

I know this question has been asked quite few times here. Went through dozen of answers, but non of them are working for me.
I am trying to re-run the `main()` when user input is `== "y"`. What my code does, when the input is "y", it asks the same question again "`try_again`". Other checks are working correctly.

Could it be that the issue is within my `main()`?
My code is below:

```
import sys


def play_again():
    '''
    Placeholder
    '''
    while True:
        try_again = input('Would you like to play again? (Y/N)\n')
        again = try_again.lower()
        if again not in ('y', 'n'):
            print("Invalid input.")
            play_again()
        if again == 'y':
            main()
        else:
            print("Goodbye")
            sys.exit()


def main():
    # all the code from the script


main()
play_again()
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]. A function can't be empty, though I'm assuming you've left out the meat of your code for the sake of example. If I put some dummy code, like `print('main!')` in `def main`, I can't reproduce the issue; it works perfectly fine for me. That said, using recursion here is not great; for better approaches, check out [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](/q/23294658/4518341). BTW, check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) if you want more tips, and take the [tour] if you haven't already

Comment: Don't use recursion for this.  You need to use a `while True:` loop, and if the user wants to exit, then you `break` the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're treating a function call like a 'go to' statement, but that's not how it works.

When you call a function in Python, the program remembers where the execution was at when the function was called, and then it jumps to the start of the function (creating a local scope for the function, which has the parameters you passed to it in it already, just like regular variables).

The function runs and when it terminates, or executes a `return` statement, it goes back to where the function was called, and continues execution from there. If a return value was provided, you can capture that by assigning it to a variable, like `x = f()`.

A function terminates without `return` when it reaches the end of the function's main body, but that's effectively the same as putting a `return None` at the end.

In your code, you call `main()` when you want to get back to the `main` function, but you probably want `return` instead. You call `play_again()` again to restart the function, but that's not needed because you're already inside a `while True` loop, which you can exit with a `break`. And calling it again, will just cause the code to return to where you called it again later - which is not what you want.

So, your code should be something like:

```
def play_again():
    while True:
        try_again = input('Would you like to play again? (Y/N)\n')
        # no need to introduce more variables, could even do this in one line
        try_again = try_again.lower()  
        if try_again not in ('y', 'n'):
            print("Invalid input.")
        elif again == 'y':
            continue  # not needed, but causes the loop start again immediately
        else:
            print("Goodbye")
            break
            # no exit required, that quits the entire script, not the function


def main():
    # all the code from the script
    play_again()
```